# How to find all rows for a particular month independent of year in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a user table with 3 columns say

> id name  dateOfBirth

where dateOfBirth is of the type DATE. Now I want to find all the people celebrating their birthday in March irrespective of the year they where born. How can it be done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE MONTH(date_column) = 3;

Answer (score 3):

Use the month function

```
Where month(dateofbirth) = 3
```

Answer (score 2):

`MySql` has [`Month`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) function:

```
WHERE MONTH(dateOfBirth) = 3
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this will be helpful.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MONTH(date) = 3
```

Regards.

Comment: -1 Question is to check the March month and not the current month

Comment: I just answered it generically, birthdays in current given month. Well i edited it. Regards @RavindraGullapalli